# How can i count to duplicates in object field using lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

I have list of Books.

```
final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
books.add(new Book(50, "Book1", 1997));
books.add(new Book(110, "Book2", 1998));
books.add(new Book(150, "Book3", 1999));
books.add(new Book(200, "Book4", 2000));
books.add(new Book(250, "Book1", 2001));
```

I tried to count duplicates by title.

```
final Integer countDuplicates = books.stream()
    .filter(b -> Collections.frequency(books, b.getTitle()) > 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).size();
```

But it's doesn't work. Help me please.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, I suspect that you haven't implemented `equals` in the Book class but you haven't shown the code...

Comment: I have implemented equals and hashCode with default Eclipse auto-generator. This has always been enough

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem you are facing. Can you describe what you expected and what happened instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-using the `frequency` method - you need to pass a collection of books and look for a book or a collection of strings and look for a string - but at the moment you pass a collection of books and look for a string - so it will always return 0.

One way would be:

```
Map<String, Long> frequency = books.stream()
    .map(Book::getTitle)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

which returns a map where the keys are the titles and the values the frequency.

If you want to count duplicates, you can do:

```
long duplicates = frequency.values().stream().filter(f -> f >= 2).count();
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you encounter is that `b.getTitle()` is not the object you are holding in your list. You hold `Book` and not its title. Furthermore you probably did not implement `Book` so that it is comparable to a `String` (which is ok).

What you could do, depends on what you are interested the most. Here is an example holding all titles and the amount of books there are in the list with that title:

```
Map<String, Long> duplicatesPerTitle = 
                          books.stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Book::getTitle, 
                                                              Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println("duplicatesPerTitle = " + duplicatesPerTitle);
```

Only interested in numbers greater 1? From here you could also just use the following:

```
duplicatesPerTitle.entrySet().stream()
                             .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
                             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a set then subtract the size of the list from the set. Make sure you use an appropriate comparator to detect duplicates.